# Javascript automatic slideshow problems

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a website for a family friend and he wanted a slideshow on the home page, I am entirely self taught so I looked on W3School on how to create an automatic slide show, but when I run the code it doesn't work. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

here is everything I have so far, any and all suggestions would be extremely helpful.

```
</div>
    <!---slideshow--->
        <div class="Slideshow-container">

            <div class="mySlides-fade">
                <img src="download.jpg" style="Width:100%">
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides-fade">
                <img src="images.jpg" style="width:100%">
            </div>

            <div class="mySlides-fade">
                <img src="welding.jpg" style="width:100%">
            </div>  

            <div class="mySlides-fade">
                <img src="rollercoaster.jpg" style="width:100%">
            </div>  

        <div style="text-align:center">
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="dot"></span>
            <span class="dot"></span>
        </div>


    </div>
    <!---start page content--->
    <div>
        <center><h2>Mission Statement</h2></center>
            <center><p>Mision statement goes here</p></center>
    </div>

<div>
    <!---javascript for slideshow--->
    <script type="text/javascript">

var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";`enter code here`
    setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
}   
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: …and please don't include pictures of your code, edit your question to include the parts of your code directly

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I edited the post to do just that.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've posted has several issues:

1. You've got an extra `}` at the end of the javascript code posted, which is throwing a general `SyntaxError`.
2. There's an extra `</div>` at the beginning of the HTML markup posted - this is invalid HTML.
3. Your `var` `slides` is targeted at the wrong class - the class `mySlides` is entirely different from the class you've defined for your elements, which is `mySlides-fade`.

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides-fade");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

```html
<!---slideshow--->
<div class="Slideshow-container">

  <div class="mySlides-fade">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" style="Width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides-fade">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/200" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides-fade">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/350/250" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides-fade">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/250/350" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div style="text-align:center">
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
    <span class="dot"></span>
  </div>


</div>
<!---start page content--->
<div>
  <center>
    <h2>Mission Statement</h2>
  </center>
  <center>
    <p>Mision statement goes here</p>
  </center>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! I made changes and everything works now!!

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the different class name in the Html which is

> `<div class="mySlides-fade">`

and in the Js code which is

> `var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");`

it should be either "mySlides-fade" or "mySlides" in both the places